# How can I launch multiple eclipse IDE with different workspaces?

Tags: eclipse, macos, launcher

I need to run multiple eclipse with different workspaces.
For Mac, I can launch eclipse using `open -a Eclipse.app --args -data WORKSPACE`. When I execute `open -a Eclipse.app --args -data DIFFERENT_WORKSPACE`, I just redirected to the existing eclipse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
open -n -a [PathToEclipse]/Eclipse.app --args -data DIFFERENT_WORKSPACE
```

`-n` will open a new instance of the application(s) even if one is already running.

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple instances of Eclipse by creating a pseudonym for Eclipse application in it's folder and using it for running new Eclipse instance