# Open Eclipse both old and new(clean)

Tags: eclipse, macos

I have a messed up Eclipse currently install the osx environment. Is it possible to run a newly downloaded Eclipse without having it interact (settings, plugins, etc.) with the currently installed one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can have more than one Eclipse installations. You just need to download Eclipse again and place it in a different location on the disk. You can run either installation of Eclipse by executing them from their respective location.

Each one will have its own setting and plugins. However by default they will both have the same project location, but of course you can change that if you want.

Comment: It's good to hear. But I'm getting the same error logs and some of the configuration from the previous Eclipse carried to the new one. Is it possible because I'm using the same workspace folder, which I shouldn't on Mac?

Comment: If the error logs are coming from errors that exist in the projects of your workspace, then you will also see them in the new installation of Eclipse. For the configuration you shouldn't have the previous ones. Make sure you are executing the correct installations. Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771888/how-can-i-launch-multiple-eclipse-ide-with-different-workspaces