# how to run omnet on multicore cpu with different workspaces?

Tags: omnet++

I want to run omnet which its IDE is based on Eclipse with different workspaces on different cores of cpu. I have found a similar question but in OSX [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771888/how-can-i-launch-multiple-eclipse-ide-with-different-workspaces).

Is there a way to do it in windows?
I could do it before, omnet just asked me for which workspace I want to use then loaded that workspace. But for some reason it stopped doing it and says `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

Comment: Can you elaborate which file is being used?

Comment: That is the thing I cannot figure out! It was working before on this computer (PC1), it is working on another computer (PC2) with the same operating system (Windows 7). But now it is not working on PC1. Since the time it was working on PC1, I installed few unrelated software like pdf reader, download manager, ...

Comment: Could you briefly explain what your ultimate goal is? There might be an easier way to achieve this than to run multiple instances of the OMNeT++ IDE

Comment: Well, I have this code to run a scenario. For the same part of my code, I would need to use different algorithms each time. Therefore, it would be very useful to have multiple workspaces and run each instance of omnet on different versions of my code on separate cores of cpu.

Comment: Maybe you have a look at the [OMNeT++ Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec329) where it is explained how to achieve exactly what you want with a single workspace. It explains how to configure your simulation correctly to make runs with different algorithms.

Comment: For running multiple simulations in parallel, I would recommend using `opp_runall` with its `-j` option.